# I install ffmpeg in the AWS EC2 environment and convert the audio .wav file to .m4a, but I'm having trouble with loud noise

Tags: ffmpeg, python, amazon-web-services, wav, m4a

I install ffmpeg in the aws EC2 environment and convert the audio wav file to m4a, but I'm having trouble with loud noise I don't know how to set parameters without noise.

The ffmpeg version is ffmpeg-5.1.1-amd64-static.

In this same environment, ffmpeg can convert video `.mov` files to `.mp4`.

## Convert .wav to .m4a

Source code:

```
if '.m4a' not in m_result.push_voice1.name:
     v_f_m4a = m_result.push_voice1.name.split('.')[0] + '.m4a' # info_audio/hoge.m4a

     dir_in = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + str(m_result.push_voice1)
     dir_out = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + v_f_m4a # lp_photo1

     stream = ffmpeg.input(dir_in) # .wav file input
     # output
     stream = ffmpeg.output(stream, dir_out) # .m4a file output
     # execution
     ffmpeg.run(stream, overwrite_output=True, capture_stdout=True, capture_stderr=True) # generate m4a
     
     dir_in = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + str(m_result.push_voice1)
     os.remove(dir_in) #media/info_audio/hoge.wav
     
     m_result.push_voice1 = v_f_m4a # Rewrite to new file name info_audio/hoge.m4a
     m_result.save() # update
```

Comment: By loud noise do you really mean unexpected extra noise or actually distortion (due to low target bitrate or so)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Not sure if related, but that code is a mess. you set `stream` to input, then you overwrite it with output and pass that to `run`...

Comment: In the development environment, it was successfully converted from .wav to .m4a with no noise.

Comment: In the aws EC2 environment, .wav is converted to .m4a, but it makes a lot of noise and is unusable.
In the EC2 environment, the instance type is t2.smal.